# Possible to load built in QML components dynamically using Component.createComponent()

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, dynamic-allocation

I want to add fonts to my application using the `FontLoader` QML component.

My first thought was to use a `Repeater`, but it only supports `Item` derived delegates, which `FontLoader` is not.

Then, my next thought was to dynamically create `FontLoader`QML components using the `Component::createComponent(url)` function, but what `url` should I use here? Is it possible to dynamically create built in QML components without providing the `url` to the qml file in `QT_INSTALL_DIR`?

**Side notes:**
I know it's possible if I subclass `FontLoader`, but I want to avoid the extra code if possible.

I also know that it's possible to use the `Component::createQmlObject()` to create a component from a string, but I really do not want to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Repeater` you could use an [`Instantiator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-instantiator.html), it allows you to dynamically create objects even if they are not `Items`s.

If you still wanted to do it imperatively, you have to use `Component` :

```
Component {
    id: fontLoaderComponent
    FontLoader {}
}
//...
fontLoaderComponent.createObject(parent, {name : "Courier"}); //use it like this to create a new FontLoader
```

Comment: I was not aware of the `Instantiator` component. It worked great!